# 500 (Internal Server Error) with WebService through AutoComplete JQuery

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, autofill

I am working with a simple autocomplete function with Jquery.

Here is the Java Script Code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#AutoCompleteText").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/Service/AutoHelp.asmx/CustomerList",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "{}",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.TEXT + '(' + item.ID + ')',
                                value: item.ID,
                                name: item.TEXT
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("In The ERROR");
                        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
```

Here is the Web Service Code

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.Script.Services

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class AutoHelp
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function

    Public Class dbHelpData
        Dim _id As String
        Dim _text As String

        Public Property ID As String
            Get
                Return _id
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _id = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property TEXT As String
            Get
                Return _text
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _text = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class

    <WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function CustomerList() As List(Of dbHelpData)
        Dim CustList As New List(Of dbHelpData)

        Dim mCustList As dbHelpData
        mCustList = New dbHelpData
        mCustList.ID = "1"
        mCustList.TEXT = "Kartik"
        CustList.Add(mCustList)

        mCustList = New dbHelpData
        mCustList.ID = "2"
        mCustList.TEXT = "Sarika"
        CustList.Add(mCustList)

        mCustList = New dbHelpData
        mCustList.ID = "3"
        mCustList.TEXT = "Yashika"
        CustList.Add(mCustList)

        Return CustList
    End Function

End Class
```

When I am trying to execute AutoFill it's giving me an error as 
POST http://ab99.pricecompareindia.com/Service/AutoHelp.asmx/CustomerList 500 (Internal Server Error) 
But I tried to execute service directly from the browser and it's giving me an XML output view as below.

```
<ArrayOfDbHelpData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <dbHelpData>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <TEXT>Kartik</TEXT>
    </dbHelpData>
    <dbHelpData>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <TEXT>Sarika</TEXT>
    </dbHelpData>
    <dbHelpData>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <TEXT>Yashika</TEXT>
    </dbHelpData>
</ArrayOfDbHelpData>
```

It's hard to figureout for me what I am doing wrong. A complete code is running at http://ab99.pricecompareindia.com/

Can anyone please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 500 indicates a server error. Start by looking at the server logs - you should find the answer there.

Comment: If possible, try to debug the web service, the actual error is there only.

Comment: `' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.`
Did you do that?

Comment: // <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>

Uncomment this line

Comment: thx.. uncomment is the right solution.. I should look on the instructions carefully, thx for your help VISH

Answer (score 0):

Place this line in your ajax:
data: '{ "prefix": "' + request.term + '"}',
and it will work exactly as happened with me.